# Hyperplane componants

Tags: linear-algebra

$W$ is a hyperplane in $R^3$ with an equation: $Ax+By+Cz= D$ where $A, B, C$ are non-zero scalars of nonzero vectors terminating in points $x, y$, and $z$ that lie in the place. The 'Normal' for the $W$ is the set of scalars $\{A, B, C\}$ with dot product $0$ with any vector that lies in the plane.

Question1: Can $2Ax+2By+2Cz= 2D$ be really in $W$? Does it not lead to another plane that is parallel to the W?

Question2: Can someone tell me (I am a beginner!) how I could derive a vector from the origin that terminates in $p$ if I create another point $p$ that is in the plane $W$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the plane $Ax+By+Cz= D$ for $D\ne 0$ is not passing throught the origin therefore  the dot product of the normal with a point in a plane in this case is not equal to zero indeed

$$(A,B,C)(x,y,z)=D$$

We can multiply the equation for any real number $\lambda\neq 0$ and we obtain exactly the same plane, the plane parallel to the one given are given by

$$Ax+By+Cz= \lambda D$$

and for $\lambda=0$ we obtain the plane throught the origin.

For question $2$, note that any $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that

$$Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0= D$$

represents a point on the plane which can also be viewd as a vector from the origin to the point $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.
I did not make it quite clear that the norm of (A, B, C) has dot product 0 with any vector lying in the plane W. I did not mean the dot product of ( A, B, C) with any of the vectors x, y, z is 0!

Comment: @Leo I get now your point but consider that vectors are always referred to the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.
I did not make it quite clear that the norm of (A, B, C) has dot product 0 with any vector lying in the plane W. I did not mean the dot product of ( A, B, C) with any of the vectors x, y, z is 0!

Furthermore, you stated that the multiples of the ENTIRE equation (Which multiplies the vectors contributing to the points x,y,z) will also be in the SAME plane. When those vectors are multiplied by different scalars don't they pierce through the plane all the three points so the new POINTs x, y, z lay in a parallel plance above the original one?

Comment: @Leo What do you mean with "those vectors are multiplied by different scalar" in the equation?

Comment: The points x, y, z in W are the points supported by three vectors in R3 with co-ordinates originating from 0...perhaps we can call those vectors p, q, and r.  And when a scalar multiplies the equation does it not multiply the supporting vectors...?

Comment: @Leo I don't fully understand what you mean by "points supported by three vectors in R3". We aree that in the cartesian form $ax+bx+cz=d$ vectors are not expilicitely involved. The points on the plane $(x,y,z)$ are the points which satisfy the equation. We can also define the plane in a parametric form by two L.I. vectors parallel to the plane (i.e. orthogonal to the normal) and one vector pointing a point on the plane. In this case vectors appears explicitely.

Comment: I guess I still am grappling with the concept of Hyperplane. The POINTS  x, y, and z ...say are 3, 2, 4,   1,2,3   and 3,1,1, and the equation is Ax+By+Cz=D where A=2, B=3 and C=1. Now if you multiply the entire equation is multiplied by 2 so that A=4, B=6 and C=2.  Does this change the POINTS x, y, z to ...x=12,8, 6   y=6,12,18  and z=3,1,1.......? and does it not put the points in a new plane?